# Shutdown and WakeUp Script C#

Tags: c#, combobox, shutdown, wake-on-lan

Hiya I am very new to C#, infact this is basically my first task set by work whilst i learn the language. Yes i am also new to programming, be gentle :).

Context:
My script needs to query active directory, grab of OU's and put them to a combo box in a form.
Next query ActDir for a list of machines in a selected OU (Done this in a vbscript already)

Next query the machines in turn for there IP, and MAC addresses.(Done this in a vbscript already)
Next needs to shut those machines down(Done this in a vbscript already) and dump all the machine and NIC info to a txt file

The other half of the script grabs the info for the machines out of the text file and sends them a magic packet to wake them up.

The shutdown section i have already written a VBscript for, but decided it wasn't future prrof, and i was learninc C# at home, so figured it was the best option to start over with.

Im not looking for anyone to write this for me, but if anyone had any pointers on where to go for information etc. . . It would be more than appreciated :)

Comment: You might get more mileage out of learning Powershell if this is the sort of space in which you're working -- far faster development and results for administrative stuff like this. You'll have a bit of a leg up with your VBScript stuff, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has all the information you need. Your AD stuff should be covered pretty well in the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace, the other stuff you can get using COM or P/Invoke.

However, to get more help here, you need to ask more specific questions. Unclear/unspecific questions often do not last long and are closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Excellent, i was looking for some direction i guess as to materials that i can use for reference, i will crack on as best i know and shout up when i inevitably encounter some issue's, almost certainly going to be something stupid to.